# Login Using MS SQL Express: Success! Migration Toolkit login: fail?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, database, migration

(no responses from my identical post on the MySQL forums & StackOverflow, so I'm hoping to have better luck here)

I'm trying to migrate a MS SQL database for a friend. I do not have physical access to the machine, nor do I have admin access -- just a read/write user.

Using "SQL Server Management Express" in XP, I can easily login using IP/user/password. I can browse tables, run queries. Easy.

When I fire up the Migration toolkit, select MS SQL, and try to connect, I get the following error:

> Connecting to source database and retrieve schemata names.
>   Initializing JDBC driver ... Driver
>   class MS SQL JDBC Driver Opening
>   connection ... Connection
>   jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MYSERVERIP:1433/MYDATABASE;user=MYUSERNAME;password=MYPASSWORD;charset=utf-8;domain=
>   The list of schema names could not be
>   retrieved (error: 0).
>   ReverseEngineeringMssql.getSchemata
>   :Login failed for user 'MYUSERNAME'.
>   Details:
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:365)
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2781)
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2224)
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:599)
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.(ConnectionJDBC2.java:331)
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:178)
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown
>   Source)
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown
>   Source)
>   com.mysql.grt.modules.ReverseEngineeringGeneric.establishConnection(ReverseEngineeringGeneric.java:141)
>   com.mysql.grt.modules.ReverseEngineeringMssql.getSchemata(ReverseEngineeringMssql.java:99)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>   com.mysql.grt.Grt.callModuleFunction(Unknown
>   Source)

Any ideas? I've triple-checked the login details, no dice. Am I missing a driver? Is the server setup weird? No idea where to go from here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to migrate to?

Comment: MSSQL 8 to MySQL 5

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you're using SQL Server Management Studio Express, is the server also SQL Server Express?

If so, then from the stack trace in your question it looks like the JDBC driver is attempting to connect to your source server by IP with no SQL instance name:

```
Connection jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MYSERVERIP:1433/MYDATABASE;user=MYUSERNAME;password=MYPASSWORD;charset=utf-8;domain=
```

which would be a default SQL Server instance.  By default, SQL Express installs a named instance called SQLEXPRESS, so my guess is that the migration toolkit is looking for a non-existent instance of SQL.  I'm not familiar with the migration toolkit, but if I'm right about your SQL instance name you should make sure it's trying to connect to your source SQL instance with SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS (where SERVERNAME is the hostname of your SQL server).

**EDIT:**

Ok, now that we've apparently ruled out an incorrect instance issue...  I would say go and get the [**newest SQL Server jdbc driver from Microsoft**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx) and try using it with the toolkit.  I've had problems in the past connecting different apps via JDBC to SQL Server using other drivers.  I'm not sure how to get the toolkit to use a different driver off the top of my head, but I'll help look for posts / instructions on how to do so.

Comment: SQL Server 8.0.2039

Where do I find the instance name?  The server is not local.

Comment: Connect in Mgmt Studio and run this from a new query window: SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition').  That'll tell you if it's Express or not.

Comment: ||
8.00.2039|SP4|Enterprise Edition

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: Hmm.  Ok blows that theory...

Comment: Thanks Squillman.  I downloaded the SQL JDBC driver from MSFT.  I then searched all over for how to swap out the drivers - couldn't find anything.  I tried simply removing the jtds.jar and renaming/replacing it with the MSFT driver...no dice.  Thank you for your continued help -- it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Building on squillman's answer - when connecting over TCP/IP, the named instances use different ports, and are most likely using "dynamic ports" (which is the default for SQLEXPRESS). Take a look at the SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration utility to figure out which port it is listening on and connect to that instead of 1433.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I don't have local access to the server, so running the Network Configuration Utility seems to only show me (local).  Can I determine the port another way?

Comment: I emailed the admin and asked him the port.  "1443" he said.  :\

Comment: Based on the fact that you are getting a login failed message (and not a connection failed) message - there is clearly a SQL Server running on 1443. My guess is you are getting a login failed message because it is not the correct SQL Server instance. Can you run a sql query to print the variable @@servername - that should tell us for sure whether you are connected to a named instance or the base instance. (Also, from there we may be able to concoct a query that pulls a port number from the registry)

Comment: OK - guess that was wrong. This shows that you are connecting to the main instance on the system, which is most likely listening on 1433. Since you are getting login failures - are you connecting using SQL authentication or Windows authentication? And if you are using Windows auth, are you putting the computername/domain into the connection string in Migration Manager?

Comment: Using SQL auth. (thanks for your continued help, Matt)

Comment: Your welcome - unfortunately, I'm pretty much out of ideas. Can you get the admin to take a look at the SQL Server logs around the time of your connection attempts to see what the error message on SQL Server's side is? That should be more helpful than the pretty generic error message you are getting from JDBC.

Comment: Based on a MySQL forum posting, I asked the admin to 1) make sure TCP/IP was enabled (it is, it's how he connects), and 2) give me any server errors at the time i tried to connect.  he responded: Error: 15457, Severity: 0, State: 1.  I researched this error, and it seems irrelevant. I *did* connect using dbVisualizer using the jtds, which means it's not a server issue.  MySQL Migration Toolkit / JRE issue?

Comment: Maybe you are missing permissions on some of the system databases/tables/views? I know the migration toolkit tries to reverse engineer your database using INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. Maybe see if you can query those through enterprise manager...

Comment: i ran "select * from information_schema.columns" and successfully retrieved results.  :(